# Create two buttons Save and Back,On click of Save button employee details should get updated .On click of Back button user should redirect

Tags: visualforce

```
  Employee_Records.vfp

  <apex:page standardController="Employee__c" recordSetVar="Employees">
        <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Employees}" var="e">
          <apex:column headerValue="Employee Name">
              <apex:outputlink value="apex/Employee_Details_Page" >{!e.Name}
              <apex:param name="id" value="{!e.id}"/></apex:outputlink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!e.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!e.EmpId__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!e.Designation__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!e.Project__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!e.Joining_Date__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!e.State__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!e.City__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageBlock>

            </apex:form>

    </apex:page>


Employee_Details_page.vfp
<apex:page standardController="Employee__c">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:detail inlineEdit="true" subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"/>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a standard controller. You can use the methods defined in the [standard controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm) on your visualforce page without needing to add "custom" buttons or a extension class.

Specifically, the methods are `Save` and `Cancel`. You can add two `apex:commandButton` tags in your `pageBlock` to match the standard styling.

```
    <apex:pageBlock >

        <!-- Should always have this when running DML --> 
        <apex:outputPanel id="Messages">
            <apex:pageMessages />
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <!-- Using Standard Controller Functions to control page flow --> 
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Employees}" var="e">
```

Comment: On click of Back button user is redirected to previous page again and this page shows updated results.So how to create back button and assosciate an action to that button

Comment: Even when i edit fields and click save command button its not getting saved